# how to fix form action to different page issue in javascript and php mysql,

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

i want to check user browser type and click form submit button to action to different page according to browser type, but when i use PHP while loop, the `<form xxxxxxx onSubmit="javascript function()">` can't run, just go `link/a.php` with two browser. If I remove the while loop, it can run successfully such as Chrome Browser to go a.php and IE Browser to go b.php. How to fix it? the code is below. The first step is import the check broswer type's javascript code from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Then this is a while loop version.

```
<script>
   function redirect(){
      if(BrowserDetect.browser == 'Chrome'){
         document.getElementById("albumlist").setAttribute("action", "link/a.php");
      }
      if(BrowserDetect.browser == 'Explorer'){
         document.getElementById("albumlist").setAttribute("action", "link/b.php");
      }
   }
</script>
```

In the `<body></body>`.

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM album GROUP BY folderName ORDER BY id desc");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $folderName = $data['folderName'];
   ...
   ...

?>

   <form name="albumlist" id="albumlist" method="post" action="link/a.php" target="_blank" onSubmit="redirect();">
      <input type="hidden" name="folderName" id="folderName" value="<?php echo $folderName; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" id="submitfolderlist" name="submitfolderlist" value="Submit" />
   </form>

<?php

}

?>
```

Then a without while loop version just remove all about `<?php while loop code ?>`

Comment: What are you doing with the data on the other side?  cuz you could just combine the page, and detect the browser with PHP on the linked to page

Comment: I do not understand your meaning, the data just pass the input value to a.php or b.php, i think the data pass to other side whether important.

Comment: Or detect the browser in the PHP script that creates the form in the first place.

Comment: You have multiple forms with same id which makes problems when refering using ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the JS to:

```
<script>
   function redirect(form){
      if(BrowserDetect.browser == 'Chrome'){
         form.setAttribute("action", "link/a.php");
      }
      if(BrowserDetect.browser == 'Explorer'){
         form.setAttribute("action", "link/b.php");
      }
   }
</script>
```

Then change your PHP to:

```
   <form name="albumlist" method="post" action="link/a.php" target="_blank" onSubmit="redirect(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="folderName" id="folderName" value="<?php echo $folderName; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="submitfolderlist" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

This gets rid of the duplicate IDs on the form and submit button.

Comment: why would this happen in my case?

Comment: Because you're printing the form inside a `while` loop, so there's form with the same ID for each row returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would just detect the browser on this current page with PHP....and change the action link accordingly.
That way you completely remove the need for javascript.

Something like this at the top of your page......

```
$ua = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
/* ==== Detect the UA ==== */
$chrome = strpos($ua, 'Chrome') ? true : false; 

// Internet Exlporer
$msie = strpos($ua, 'MSIE') ? true : false; 
// All Internet Explorer

if($chrome){ $link = "link/a.php";}
elseif($msie){$link = "link/b.php";}
```

Then in your form just echo out the $link variable for the action...

```
<form name="albumlist" id="albumlist" method="post" action="<?echo $link;?>" target=_blank>
```

PS Totally untested...Im just giving you an idea...